# Make website action work on noscript

Tags: html, css, noscript

I've a website that have to work with javascript disabled web browsers, this website has a lot of jquery animations that controls the display of content. I've already make the content correctly appear using `<style>` inside `<noscript>` tags to modify the "display" CSS rule.

Now I'm stuck, I've a form that appears when somebody does click on a button, right now this action is catched by a jquery function that modify a  "display" value but I don't know how to do something like that with CSS.

I've in mind something like using .button-class:active rule but I'll need to modify another CSS rule to make it appear

Here's an example

```
    .hide-div{
    width:300px;
    display:none;
    }

.mybutton:active {
How can I change ".hide-div" "display" value from here?
}
```

Comment: Is the `.hide-div` inside the `.mybutton:active`?

Comment: Not sure you can. The button could issue a GET request with a query parameter that flags that the form should be shown. Then on the server side modify the class or display value of the form or simply include the form in the markup at that point.

Comment: Make the form show by default (no display:none in CSS) and make the script hide it on page load. That way if script runs it gets hidden and shown on click but if JavaScript is turned off then it still shows. I believe this is the proper approach to "graceful degradation". If you want I can post a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach:

**HTML**

```
<a class="show">Show</a>
<div class="hidden">I'm hidden!
    <input type="text" /></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.show:active ~ .hidden, 
.hidden:hover {
    display: block!important;
}
```

**Explain:**

The ~ selector, selects any sibling element of the left element, after itself. When the button (or link) is pressed, the div shows, and while the user hovers the div, the form will stay visible.

**Fiddle:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/1y0jrzs9/9/

**UPDATE**

You can add the follow css rule, to avoid the difficult of hover fast the form, or hover with the click pressed.

```
.hidden:before {
    z-index: 999;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: relative; 
    top: -30px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

The pseudo-element count as a part of the div, so when it displays, it considered hovered.

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to use a hidden input to style some other content as long as it's a sibling or within a sibling of the input. In this case the input is displaying the form element. Because the input is hidden it really just looks like whatever you put in the label is triggering the change:

HTML

```
<div class="switchContainer">
    <label for="hiddenInput1" onclick><button>Show the form</button></label>
    <input type="radio" id="hiddenInput1" value="shown" />
    <form>I'm a form this time but could be anything really</form>
</div>
```

the empty onclick is to ensure it works on iOS < 6.0

CSS

```
/* hide the input */
.switchContainer input[type=radio] {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}

.switchContainer label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Default State of altered element */
.switchContainer form {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    margin: 1ex 0;
    padding: 1.6em;
    display: none;
}

/* 'checked' styles for altered element */
.switchContainer input[type=radio]:checked ~ form {
    display: block;
}
```

There's also the caveat where the CSS:

```
body {
    -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s; 
}
@-webkit-keyframes bugfix { 
  from {padding:0;} 
  to {padding:0;} 
}
```

is needed to ensure it works on Android <= 4.1.2

https://jsfiddle.net/mLyjk9r4/

In the example above you can only display the element (the radio can't be unchecked) - if you want to be able to toggle it you can use a checkbox which will let you uncheck the item reverting the styles (in this case hiding the form again)

https://jsfiddle.net/1L8pmb90/

It seems pretty versatile and fun to play around with a bit

https://jsfiddle.net/ks38r6v9/

Picked up from:

http://timpietrusky.com/advanced-checkbox-hack